# Is it possible to print barcodes vertically using POS for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, barcode-printing

please help me. I am new to c# POS .net printing and I am using an EPSON TM-T81 thermal printer for my project.

I already know how to print barcodes horizontally using the PosPrinter.PrintBarBarcode method but my problem is I want to print the barcode vertically.

I can print vertically any text using PosPrinter.RotatePrint method provided that i specify its PrintRotation to any of the following enums:
Left90,Normal,Rigth90,Rotate180,Barcode,Bitmap

I noticed that the PrintRotaion contains both Barcode and Bitmap so I thought that I can also print barcode vertically using the PosPrinter.RotatePrint and i did this:

```
//the PosPrinter obj is named printer and has already been opened,claimed and enabled
printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Barcode);
printer.PrintBarCode(PrinterStation.Receipt,"123",BarCodeSymbology.Code128,printer.RecLineHeight,printer.RecLineWidth,PosPrinter.PrinterBarCodeCenter,BarCodeTextPosition.Below);
//stop rotation and back to normal printing
printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Normal);
```

This code will perfectly compile but when i start to execute the code, an exception will be handled as I have used try-catch in this block.

This is the Exception:

> Method RotatePrint threw an exception.  Attempt was made to perform an illegal or unsupported operation with the device, or an invalid parameter value was used.

I read the PrintRotation.Barcode description and it says:

> Rotate barcode printing. (ORed with one of the above rotation values.)

Now, what does the "(ORed with one of the above rotation values.)" mean?
Do I have to specify another PrintRotation enum before my block of code like this?

the PosPrinter obj is named printer and has already been opened,claimed and enabled

```
//I added this
printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Left90);

printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Barcode);
printer.PrintBarCode(PrinterStation.Receipt, "123", BarCodeSymbology.Code128, printer.RecLineHeight,printer.RecLineWidth,PosPrinter.PrinterBarCodeCenter,BarCodeTextPosition.Below);
printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Normal);
```

When i try to execute these statements i still get the same exception.

Please help me.
Can barcode be printed vertically?
Is this is not the way to print the barcode vertically?
Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

"(ORed with one of the above rotation values.)" Means use the bitwise OR operator to join the two enum values.

```
printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Barcode | PrintRotation.Left90);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check available rotation before attempting to rotate since it may not be supported. In my case with Star Printer tsp100, only 'Normal' and 'Rotate180' is supported.

```
var rotationList = m_Printer.RecBarCodeRotationList;
```